# Semiconductor-level genetic programming

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, fpga, semiconductors

I was reading an old article about Adrian Thompson's work on using genetic programming to generate circuit solutions for simple tasks such as frequency differentiation.

This got me wondering: every gate in a circuit is just a collection of transistors, so could there be efficient transistor-level optimizations, which may not really have any gate equivalents, that can be detected by GPs or some other clever group of algorithms?

And getting really low level, transistors are just collections of blocks of doped semiconductors with wiring appropriately placed. If we had transistor-level optimal designs, could they in principle be fast and efficient enough for us to explore the space of ways to stack different configurations of just wire and doped materials to get a job done, foregoing even transistors for rich complexes of various blocks of material interacting in, at this point very non-trivial, ways?

Comment: There have been project that did similar to this with FPGA's, however in certain circumstances the resulting device became susceptible to temperature variations that killed the required function. https://books.google.co.uk/books?isbn=0470049707 it's not the article I was looking for but a bit similar

Comment: @Spoon: not only to temperature variations, but in case of analogue  like circuits, the algorithm had to run per physical chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "foregoing even transistors instead for rich complexes of various blocks of material interacting in, at this point very non trivial, ways"

Possible, but not for practical consumer applications, that rely on digital circuits. Fabrication of chips happen in semiconductor "fabs", which inevitably results in manufacturing defects. Design for Test (DFT) algorithms are used today to bring quality chips to the market. DFT algorithms work on digital logic circuits.

Design happens at the architectural level and is then refined to logic and gates. Digital circuits have many advantages over analog circuits, including testability and reliability.